# Unable to load unmanaged dll into azure function .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-functions, dllimport

I am attempting to load an unmanaged vendor .dll file from Azure function using "DllImport" but It throws error "Unable to load DLL '.\Lib\abc.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)" . I spent a lot of time in google but I did not find a solution to resolve. My file is in a lib folder under project. I used VS 2019.

[DllImport(".\Lib\abc.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "calc")]
public static extern double calc(double a, double b, double c);

I also tried in ASP.net core web api. I got same error.
Any idea/hints/solution to resolve my issue. Thanks.

Comment: Be sure your dll has the right bitness. By default Azure functions are 32 bits. Also, ensure the dll is really on that path. An complete full stack of the exception would help to understand better your issue

Comment: I do not know how to check bitness of a dll file but I  built separately both x86 and x64.

Comment: @oscar. Set x86 and run Azure function, the log info in 
console is "[2021-07-21] Found C:\...\AzureFunctionNetCore\AzureFunctionNetCore.csproj. 
Using for user secrets file configuration.
[2021-07-21] A host error has occurred during startup operation 'a256d9d8-964e-4319-a5ee-26858cc9b905'.
[2021-07-21] System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 'AzureFunctionNetCore, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider') ...
[2021-07-21] Host unavailable after check. Returning error.

Comment: @oscar. Set 64 as build. app throws exception. error as follows
System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (0x8007000B)
   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.InternalLoadUnmanagedDllFromPath(String unmanagedDllPath)
   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadUnmanagedDllFromPath(String unmanagedDllPath)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionAssemblyLoadContext.LoadUnmanagedDll(String unmanagedDllName) 
in :\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\DotNet\FunctionAssemblyLoadContext.cs:line 449

Comment: @oscar. File path is correct. Lib folder is under project root
i also set CopyToOutput directory -- copy always. 
I also tried ASP.net Core web api same error

Comment: @oscar. I used dumpbin to find bitness. it is 32 bit dll.  FILE HEADER VALUES
14C machine (x86).  Any more idea.

Comment: I am getting the same error even if I build an ASP.net core web application. Can anyone tell me the root cause of the problem? Give me some good links that I would research. I am stuck due to this problem.